# SQL - GROUP BY and PARTITION OVER Query - Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get a table of an average for a column, across multiple rows (if that makes sense).

For example, in the table below, I need to group the postcodes (as there can be more than 1 suburb to a postcode), but also group the property and rooms, to return an average across those particular rows.

Sample table:

| postcode | suburb | property | rooms | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | A | apartment | 1 | 100,000 |
| 0001 | A | apartment | 2 | 200,000 |
| 0001 | A | house | 1 | 100,000 |
| 0001 | A | house | 2 | 200,000 |
| 0001 | A | house | 3 | 300,000 |
| 0001 | B | house | 1 | 50,000 |
| 0001 | B | apartment | 2 | 150,000 |

Desired outcome:

| property | rooms | avg_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apartment | 1 | 100,000 |
| apartment | 2 | 175,000 |
| house | 1 | 75,000 |
| house | 2 | 200,000 |
| house | 3 | 300,000 |

So I have averaged apartments with 2 rooms across the 2 suburbs, but within the 1 postcode. Likewise for 1 bedroom houses.

My attempt is below. Without the `group by` at the end, it returns duplicate rows, with the `group by` it returns 1 row.

```
"SELECT `property`, `rooms`, ROUND(AVG(`price`) 
OVER (PARTITION BY `property`,`rooms`),0) 
AS avg_price FROM `suburbs` WHERE `postcode` = '0001' GROUP BY `postcode`
```

I suspect I need to nest the `postcode` first, then do the `partition over`, but not working. Can someone please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is not clear. How does the postcode come into play? Your sample table shows data for one postcode only, so what would the result look like for two or more postcodes?

Anyway, it seems you have not really understood what `GROUP BY` does. `GROUP BY x, y, z` means "I want one result row per x, y, z combination". You group by postcode, so you get one result row per postcode. As you also limit your data to postcode '0001', you get one result row of course.

You also confuse **aggregation functions** where you condense your data to less rows and show the average (`AVG`), sum (`SUM`), whatever per group, with **analytic functions**, where you keep the original rows and add an aggregation gained from the result data set, for which you use `AVG OVER`, `SUM OVER` etc.

You want aggregation. You don't want to show the original rows from the table, but group rows per property and rooms.

Now to the postcode. What do you want to do? Do you want to select data for postcode '0001' only and show one result row per property and rooms? Then

```
SELECT
  property,
  rooms,
  ROUND(AVG(price), 0) AS avg_price
FROM suburbs
WHERE postcode = '0001'
GROUP BY property, rooms
ORDER BY property, rooms;
```

Or do you want to show this for all postcodes separately? Then you must select the postcode along and put it in your `GROUP BY` clause, so as to get one result row per postcode, property and rooms.

```
SELECT
  postcode,
  property,
  rooms,
  ROUND(AVG(price), 0) AS avg_price
FROM suburbs
GROUP BY postcode, property, rooms
ORDER BY postcode, property, rooms;
```

I should add that your query is invalid as can be seen here: https://dbfiddle.uk/h36YNfh3. You group by postcode, but you select property and rooms. There can be more than one property and rooms for a postcode, so which would you want to select? You say that you can run your query and get one result row. This indicates that you are running MySQL in a cheat mode that allows you to write invalid `GROUP BY` queries. It is all the more surprising that your version suppports window function (aka analytic functions). If I remember correctly, window functions got introduced in MySQL 8, and the cheat mode that was the default in earlier versions was no longer the default then. Have you deliberately removed the default `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from the modes? Never do this. Always have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` switched on when working with MySQL, no matter which version. Otherwise the DBMS will let you write invalid queries as in your example and not warn you about it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this :

```
SELECT
  property,
  rooms,
  AVG(price) AS avg_price
FROM
  suburbs
WHERE
  postcode = '0001'
GROUP BY
  property,
  rooms
ORDER BY
  property,
  rooms;
```

Comment: Your query works correctly, see https://dbfiddle.uk/w66WfWYC. Since your `WHERE` clause fetches one postcode only, you don't need the postcode in the `GROUP BY` clause (I removed it in the sample fiddle).

Comment: Thanks, please mark it as solved , Lets help the community as well :)

Comment: Marking queestions as solved must be done by their author

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Tell the OP what you think is wrong in their algorithm, understanding or query and how your solution addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH AvgPrices AS (
  SELECT `property`, `rooms`, ROUND(AVG(`price`), 0) AS avgprice
    FROM `TableOne`
   WHERE `postcode` = '0001'
GROUP BY `property`, `property`, `rooms`
)
SELECT * FROM AvgPrices;
```

Comment: Why the CTE, when you select all data from it without any further filtering or modification?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the duplicates using "Distinct" Key Word

```
 SELECT Distinct property, room, ROUND(AVG(price) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY property,rooms),0) 
    AS avg_price FROM `suburbs`
    WHERE postcode = '0001'
```

Comment: Why would you use an `OVER` clause to keep the original rows and then use `DISTINCT`, because you don't want the original rows? That doesn't make much sense. If you want to aggregate per property and room, then aggregate without `OVER` as shown in the other answers.